# Datatable paging buttons not sending start argument correctly when using webpack builder

Tags: jquery, datatable

Here is my code:

```
$('#myTable')
        .DataTable({
          'oLanguage': {
            'sSearch': 'Search Username'
          },
          'processing': true,
          'serverSide': true,
          'paging': true,
          'ordering': false,
          'autoWidth': false,
          'pageLength': 10,
          'ajax': {
            'url': '/someUrl',
            'dataSrc': 'someData',
            'type': 'POST'
          },
          'dom': 'Bfrtip',
          'buttons': [
            'csv', 'excel'
          ],
          'columns': [
            { 'data': '_id' },
            { 'data': 'username' },
            { 'data': 'amount' },
            {
              'data': 'action',
              render: function (data, type, row) {}
            }
          ]
        });
```

when clicking on page 2 or any other button (including first, last, next,...) the value of start and length in request body is always sent as 0 and 10 and only showing first 10 results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In webpack entry file when using `require` function to load `datatables.net`, we have to do it correctly and define it on `window` and `jQuery` object.

Wrong way:

```
require('datatables.net-bs');
```

Correct way:

```
require('datatables.net-bs')( window, $ );
```

then we just need to build our bundle again and every thing works just fine.

- Remember to NOT use `datatables.net` and `datatables.net-bs` together. If you are using bootstrap just use `datatables.net-bs`.